# Not able to change /usr/bin permission - Permission denied

Tags: permissions, putty

When I logged into my linux box via Winscp. I see /usr/bin is owned by root and others are owned by the user name which I am logging in. How much ever ,I tried to change the permission of /usr/bin I am not able to do. Trying Sudo -s asks for my password. When entered, tells "Please try again" and after 3 attempts fails. Please suggest if there is any way ,i can have full permission for /usr/bin with some default password?

Comment: You should **not** try to change the permissions or ownership of the `/usr/bin` directory. No there is not a default password - if you have forgotten yours or removed your account from the `sudo` group you will need to reset it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you cannot remeber your password anymore, or are not part of the sudo group, you won't be able to `sudo` anymore. There is no such thing as a "default password".

***Edit***: Just saw the comment of @steeldriver with similar content now.

Comment: Thanks @Marcus ,I tried to add the user to sudo group by sudo adduser <username> sudo. It fails with the same reason. Sorry ,try again and the after 3 rd attempt terminates. What does this mean? Am I not even allowed to add the user to the group?

Comment: @PreethiJha it usually just means you are not typing the correct password: if your user account did not belong to the sudo group it should say something like `xxx is not in the sudoers file` and not even ask for a password. You can check your group membership using the `id` command.

Comment: @steeldriver , I checked my user with id command. I get uid=1353(cware) gid=1353(cware) groups=1353(cware). I am giving the same password with which ,I am logging into the server box for user "cware" in my case.Only thing now I doubt is that, my password starts with $ symbol .Will that be a problem to the shell?

Comment: @steeldriver , I am actually using the sudo command for following:  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/javac" 1 . Once after entering the password when prompted, It will wait for a while and then display message "Sorry,try again" . After 3 attempt it fails.